# Finding the max/min value in an array of primitives using Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, frameworks

It's trivial to write a function to determine the min/max value in an array, such as:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param chars
 * @return the max value in the array of chars
 */
private static int maxValue(char[] chars) {
    int max = chars[0];
    for (int ktr = 0; ktr < chars.length; ktr++) {
        if (chars[ktr] > max) {
            max = chars[ktr];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

but isn't this already done somewhere?

Comment: Array of primitive to array of containers would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770289/converting-array-of-primitives-to-array-of-containers-in-java followed by `Collections.max(Arrays.asList())`.

Comment: I just love how dumb the Java is

Comment: Arrays.asList won't work on an array of a primitive type\.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Using Commons Lang (to convert) + Collections (to min/max)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

public class MinMaxValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = {'3', '5', '1', '4', '2'};

        List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(a));

        System.out.println(Collections.min(b));
        System.out.println(Collections.max(b));
   }
}
```

Note that `Arrays.asList()` wraps the underlying array, so it should not be too memory intensive and it should not perform a copy on the elements of the array.

Comment: what is `ArrayUtils`

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` should be fine, but `ArrayUtils.toObject()` will copy each element of `a` to a new array of `Character`.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(a)` doesn't work. You can't make a list of primitives (`List<char>` in this case). First you need to convert the primitive values to objects and that's why `ArrayUtils.toObject` is used.

Answer (score 169):

You can simply use the new Java 8 [`Stream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) but you have to work with `int`.

The [`stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) method of the utility class [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) gives you an [`IntStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) on which you can use the [`min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--) method. You can also do [`max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--), [`sum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--), [`average`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--),...

The [`getAsInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#getAsInt--) method is used to get the value from the [`OptionalInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] tab = {12, 1, 21, 8};
        int min = Arrays.stream(tab).min().getAsInt();
        int max = Arrays.stream(tab).max().getAsInt();
        System.out.println("Min = " + min);
        System.out.println("Max = " + max)
    }

}
```

**==UPDATE==**

If execution time is important and you want to go through the data only once you can use the [`summaryStatistics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--) method like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;

public class SOTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] tab = {12, 1, 21, 8};
        IntSummaryStatistics stat = Arrays.stream(tab).summaryStatistics();
        int min = stat.getMin();
        int max = stat.getMax();
        System.out.println("Min = " + min);
        System.out.println("Max = " + max);
    }
}
```

This approach can give better performance than classical loop because the [`summaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--) method is a [reduction operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and it allows parallelization.

Answer (score 61):

The [Google Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has min and max methods in its Chars, Ints, Longs, etc. classes.

So you can simply use:

```
Chars.min(myarray)
```

No conversions are required and presumably it's efficiently implemented.

Comment: It's implemented more or less like in the question except it throws an IllegalArgumentException for an array of length 0. (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.java)

Comment: This is the best solution of everything here. Avoids all that java.util.Arrays#asList varargs confusion.

Answer (score 25):

By sorting the array, you get the first and last values for min / max.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class apples {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {2,5,3,7,8};
    Arrays.sort(a);

    int min =a[0];
    System.out.println(min);

    int max= a[a.length-1];
    System.out.println(max);
  }
    
}
```

Although the sorting operation is more expensive than simply finding min/max values with a simple loop. But when performance is not a concern (e.g. small arrays, or your the cost is irrelevant for your application), it is a quite simple solution.

Note: the array also gets modified after this.

Comment: I think what this means to say is that if you sort the array (in ascending order), by definition, the minimum value will always be at the first position, a[0], and the maximum value will always be at the last position, [a.length-1].

Comment: This is a legitimate and useful way of solving the problem. What's the disadvantage of using it compared to the other ones?

Comment: @alex time complexity - sorting is at best an O(nlogn) affair, while Michael Rutherfurd approach is O(n).

Comment: We dont need sort as single iteration over list is enough to find min and max.

Comment: @akhil_mittal but this requires more code than a sort, because there is no Java standard method to do this iteration

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it's done in the [Collections](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)) class. Note that you will need to convert your primitive char array to a Character[] manually.

A short demo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static Character[] convert(char[] chars) {
        Character[] copy = new Character[chars.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            copy[i] = Character.valueOf(chars[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = {'3', '5', '1', '4', '2'};
        Character[] b = convert(a);
        System.out.println(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(b)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Collections.min(myCollection); If you want to use it for arrays, you can do it like Collections.min(Arrays.asList(myArray));

Comment: converting a `char []` to a `Character []` only to determine the maximum is quite inefficient - better create a utility class with static methods for each primitive type similar to `java.util.Arrays`: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: @Christoph: yes, if the size of the array is large, I would agree. Simply stating it is "inefficient" does not make sense if the application in question makes many database calls and/or I/O operations and the size of the array is (relative) small.

Comment: you should use `Character.valueOf(chars[i])` instead of `new Character(chars[i])` for performance reasons: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#valueOf%28char%29

Comment: @Christoph Christoph is right, it is inefficient and stupid to transform an array to an Collection, for min max search.

Answer (score 11):

I have a little helper class in all of my applications with methods like:

```
public static double arrayMax(double[] arr) {
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    for(double cur: arr)
        max = Math.max(max, cur);

    return max;
}
```

Comment: You should use 
double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
instead of 
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
As MIN_VALUE for double is positive

Comment: ... or you could set max to the first item in the array, and iterate from the 2nd item, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a utility class providing `min/max` methods for primitive types: [Primitives.java](http://pastebin.com/f57ae8d47)

```
int [] numbers= {10,1,8,7,6,5,2};
    int a=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int c:numbers) {
        a=c<a?c:a;
        }
        
    System.out.println("Lowest value is"+a);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could easily do it with an `IntStream` and the `max()` method.

#### Example

```
public static int maxValue(final int[] intArray) {
  return IntStream.range(0, intArray.length).map(i -> intArray[i]).max().getAsInt();
}
```

#### Explanation

1. `range(0, intArray.length)` - To get a stream with as many elements as present in the `intArray`.
2. `map(i -> intArray[i])` - Map every element of the stream to an actual element of the `intArray`.
3. `max()` - Get the maximum element of this stream as `OptionalInt`.
4. `getAsInt()` - Unwrap the `OptionalInt`. (You could also use here: `orElse(0)`, just in case the `OptionalInt` is empty.)

Answer (score 3):

```
    public int getMin(int[] values){
        int ret = values[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
            ret = Math.min(ret,values[i]);
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: This is for numbers `int` but the question is asking for primitive values `int, long, char, byte....`

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int a[] = new int [100];
   Random rnd = new Random ();

    for (int i = 0; i< a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = rnd.nextInt(99-0)+0;
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

    int max = 0;          

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = max;


        for (int j = i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
            if (a[j] > max) {
               max = a[j];
            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Max element: " + max);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `reduce()`:

```
int[] array = {23, 3, 56, 97, 42};
// directly print out
Arrays.stream(array).reduce((x, y) -> x > y ? x : y).ifPresent(System.out::println);

// get the result as an int
int res = Arrays.stream(array).reduce((x, y) -> x > y ? x : y).getAsInt();
System.out.println(res);
>>
97
97
```

In the code above, `reduce()` returns data in `Optional` format, which you can convert to `int` by `getAsInt()`.

If we want to compare the max value with a certain number, we can set a start value in `reduce()`:

```
int[] array = {23, 3, 56, 97, 42};
// e.g., compare with 100
int max = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(100, (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y);
System.out.println(max);
>>
100
```

In the code above, when `reduce()` with an identity (start value) as the first parameter, it returns data in the same format with the identity. With this property, we can apply this solution to other arrays:

```
double[] array = {23.1, 3, 56.6, 97, 42};
double max = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(array[0], (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y);
System.out.println(max);
>>
97.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 IntStream.of(a).max().getAsInt()
```

Example:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {3, 7, 5, 2};
        int max = IntStream.of(a).max().getAsInt();
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example with float:

```
public static float getMaxFloat(float[] data) {

    float[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    return copy[data.length - 1];
}

public static float getMinFloat(float[] data) {

    float[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    return copy[0];
}
```

Comment: While your solution will work, but it will increase the time complexity to O(nlogn) while min can be found easily in O(n) by using other answers.

Comment: simply crazy to use a sort in this situation.

Comment: It can be useful when the first n>1 smallest/largest value is needed, with some repairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use `Arrays.stream()` to get Max Value from a primitive array in Java.

```
int [] numbers = {10,1,8,7,6,5,2};
int maxValue = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();
System.out.println(maxValue);
```

Comment: Other questions have provided this as part of an answer, but none as the main point of the answer or as succinctly.  +1 from me, and I think this makes sense as its own distinct answer from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array to a method that sorts it with `Arrays.sort()` so it only sorts the array the method is using then sets *min* to `array[0]` and *max* to `array[array.length-1]`.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that a) this modifies the array, and b) for large arrays it's a more expensive solution O(nlog n) rather than O(n)

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to get the min/max value of an Array. If you need the unsorted array, you may create a copy or pass it to a method that returns the min or max. If not, sorted array is better since it performs faster in some cases.

```
public class MinMaxValueOfArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {2, 4, 3, 5, 5};
        Arrays.sort(A);
        int min = A[0];
        int max = A[A.length -1];
        System.out.println("Min Value = " + min);        
        System.out.println("Max Value = " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with sorting is that it has an O(n log n) overhead for a O(n) problem.  But this is better than the other three "sort the array" answers already given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to get the max value in about 99% of runs (change the 0.01 to get a better result):

```
public static double getMax(double[] vals){
    final double[] max = {Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY};

    IntStream.of(new Random().ints((int) Math.ceil(Math.log(0.01) / Math.log(1.0 - (1.0/vals.length))),0,vals.length).toArray())
            .forEach(r -> max[0] = (max[0] < vals[r])? vals[r]: max[0]);

    return max[0];
}
```

(Not completely serious)

Comment: ;-) That’s “Not completely serious” alright. Hesitating to upvote…

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    int max_ = Collections.max(list);
    int i;
    if (max_ > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i < Collections.max(list); i++) {
            if (!list.contains(i)) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==max_){
            System.out.println(i+1);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: What question does this answer, and how?