# program to find the largest number in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Let us imagine that we are having a arraylist in java which contains both intergers and strings value. I would like to loop through the entire arraylist(only taking the integers,ignore string) to find the largest number on the list???i need a program for this task????help me please

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/java-max-min-value-in-an-array

Comment: Use a for-loop with an `instanceof` check.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming an Object ArrayList, something like this *should* work:

```
int biggest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (Object item : list) {
    if(item instanceof Integer && (Integer) item > biggest)
        biggest = item;
}
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't keep different data types in a list. Use generics extensively.
2. you can use instanceOf (ArrayList keeps Integers and Strings) to check type and put the int's seperately and get the largest value.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getLargestNumber(ArrayList<Objects> list){
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        Object obj = list.get(i);
        if(obj instanceof Integer && max < (Integer) obj)
                max = (Integer)obj;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a ArayList object to the below function it will return the bigest Integer from the list ..

```
 public static Integer getLargerInteger(ArrayList list){
    ArrayList temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Object object : list) {
        if(object instanceof Integer){
            temp.add(object);
        }
    }
    return Collections.max(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach using Comparator Interface rather then looping through all the elements.

```
    List arr = new ArrayList();
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(5);
    arr.add(10);
    arr.add(20);
    arr.add("s1");
    arr.add("s2");
    arr.add("s3");

    Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Object>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            if(o1 instanceof Integer && o2 instanceof Integer){
                Integer ob1 = (Integer) o1;
                Integer ob2 = (Integer) o2;
                return ob2.compareTo(ob1);
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }

    });
    System.out.println(arr.get(0));
```