# Maximum in a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, methods, max

Say I have a matrix,

```
1 0 1
0 2 0
3 2 1
```

Is there a built in method in Java that would output the number 3 (the maximum) along with its coordinates?

If not then I think [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) might have spoiled me, hehe.

Comment: there is no specific java library. So search for any external library like `commons-math`

Comment: what do you mean a library? does that mean ill have to dl code and add it to my library of methods sry if this sounds stupid =/

Comment: Java does not really have matrices built in, beyond just 2-D arrays.

Comment: @matt: something like this http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/

Comment: @arunmoezhi Can commons-math actually do this?

Comment: @DavidWallace: I don't know. Thats why I asked him to search for external libraries like `commons-math`. If I knew the the exact library and the method then I would have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: If the matrix is an `int[][]`: `Stream.of(matrix).flatMapToInt(e -> Arrays.stream(e)).max().orElseThrow()`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the "matrix". As far as my experience with Java goes (and a brief Google search), there is no "standard" matrix class so I assume you are either using a multi-dimensional array (`int[][] matrix`) or some 3rd party library.

In the former case, Java does provide the means for finding the max of a *Collection*. I assume it could somehow be applied to a multi-dimensional array; **however** it involves converting the array to a collection which, [as this SO post points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/java-max-min-value-in-an-array), is very inefficient if all you need is min/max. Instead, you should write the min/max function yourself. Either it will be trivial for you and require little effort or you will learn something from doing it.

If you are using a 3rd party library, such as [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/), then it entirely depends on the implementation of that library and I recommend you consult its documentation or source.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code that will do the maximum.

```
public FunRun()
{
    int[][] array = { { 1, 1, 2 }, { 1, 0, 3 }, { 0, 2, 1 } };
    System.out.println(max(array, 3, 3));
}

Integer max(int[][] array, int rows, int cols)
{
    Integer result = null;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            if (result == null || result < array[row][col])
            {
                result = array[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sry but on this line:                                               if (result == null || result < array[row][col]) what does "||" do?

Comment: That is the logical or in java.