# Finding Minimum Number Of An Array?

Tags: arrays

So I am making a program where you write 10 marks and it tells you the maximum and the minimum.

I Have a problem with the Minimum,as the maximum does work.

My problem is that instead of the worst mark,it shows me the first mark entered.

This Is Using Jcreator(Java)

```
   public void worstEnglish() {
        System.out.println("The Worst English Mark Is");
        //Array
        int worstEnglish = english[0];
        //Method
        for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
            if (english[i] < worstEnglish) {
                english[i] = worstEnglish;
            }//End Of If
        }//End of loop
    }
```

Comment: Add mode code to make it clear.

Answer (score 4):

you are assigning the value of worstEnglish variable to english array instead of the other way around

```
if(english[i] < worstEnglish){
    worstEnglish = english[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 worstEnglish = english[i];
```

Swap the assignment. Right now you are not updating the worstEnglish variable.

```
public void worstEnglish() {
System.out.println("The Worst English Mark Is");
//Array
int worstEnglish = english[0];
//Method
for (int i=0; i<english.length; i++){
if(english[i] < worstEnglish){
  worstEnglish = english[i];
}//End Of If
}//End of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simplifying this with `Collections.min()` and `Collections.max()` instead of doing iterations over the Arrays?

Since you've typed the worstEnglish array as Int, I'm assuming these are Integer values in the array.

I'd image it'd be just `worstEnglish = Collection.min(english);`

See this SO for example: [Finding the max/min value in an array of primitives using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/java-max-min-value-in-an-array)