# Java collection to find maximum number

Tags: java, eclipse, max

How to find maximum number in this program I am new to collection so please help me. Thanks in advance

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {   
       Integer inums[] = {4,8,0,6,1};
       Stats<Integer> iob = new Stats<Integer>(inums);
       int i = iob.getmax();
       System.out.println("maximum value is" );

       Double dums[] = {7.1,3.2,9.1,9.4,5.5};
       Stats<Double> dob = new Stats<Double>(dums);
       double d = dob.getmax();
       System.out.println("maximum value is");

       Float fnums[] = {8.1f,5.9f,9.7f,7.4f};
       Stats<Float> fob = new Stats<Float>(fnums);
       float f = fob.getmax();
       System.out.println("maximum value is");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Stats a new class to define getmax() function

Comment: What parts of Stats have you written yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: If i am declaring int and getting double and float error so I am unable to write in genric.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-using-java

Comment: Show that code anyways. Have you looked at some basic tutorials on Generics?

Comment: check my answer below. it should work for any array you pass to it.

Comment: The above program is read only program I can not alter in this program so need to write complete stats class inorder to get proper output

Comment: that program is read only file using that program we have to write stats class to get the maximum value given in above program. I am new to programming so unable to understand the proper way to write

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection containing the desired numbers, all you need to do is

```
Collections.max(myCollection,null);
```

This will sort according to the natural ordering of the elements in the collection.

In your case, that max value will be something like:

```
int i=Collections.max(iob);
```

and so on for each of the cases, if your Stats is a collection.

Comment: for more help, please provide also the Stats class implementation.

Comment: Did you know that there is a `Arrays.asList()` method? However the exercise of OP is about writing their own generic class, not using an existing one.

Comment: I removed that information, but i was thinking that seeing how it is solved with ArrayList it would be easier for him to figure out how to implement it himself.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any array you have.

```
  class Stats<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> {

    public Stats(){}

    public T getMax(T[] list)
    {

        T maxElement = list[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) 
        {
            if (maxElement.compareTo(list[i]) == -1)
            {
                maxElement = list[i];
            }
        }

        return maxElement;
    }
```

Comment: I think this does miss the point of the exercise - a generic class `Stats`

Comment: Wait, I dont understand what you are saying? Could you rephrase that?

Comment: OP says in the comment "Stats a new class to define getmax() function" - so this code needs to be in that new class, that new class needs to support generic types

Comment: I didnt see it in the OP, thanks for that. I have changed it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The constructor Stats<Integer>(Integer[]) is undefined
 The method getmax() is undefined for the type Stats<Integer>
 The constructor Stats<Double>(Double[]) is undefined
 The method getmax() is undefined for the type Stats<Double>
 The constructor Stats<Float>(Float[]) is undefined
 The method getmax() is undefined for the type Stats<Float>

 at Main.main(Main.java:6)
If i am using your program the above errors are coming

Comment: The method `getMax()` I wrote takes an argument of an Array, from the stack trace you provided, you didnt pass it any argument, also, the constructor doesnt take any arguments. You are not doing it correctly. To use this class, instantiate it like this `Stats<Integer> stats = new Stats<>();` , then to use the `getMax()` method, do this `stats.getMax(integerArray);`

Comment: Sir please explain a bit more.

Comment: When you look at my code, you can see that the constructor doesnt take any argument since there is nothing in the parenthesis, so when you create a new object of the `Stats` class, you dont pass to it any thing like this `Stats<Integer> stats = new Stats<Integer>()`. Then, lets assume that you have an array of `Integer` called `integerArray` , looking at the method `getMax()`, inside the parenthesis, it requires an array of some type that is the subtype of `Comparable` interface, so you pass it your Integer array like this `stats.getMax(integerArray)`