# Finding min element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Testing out code to find the min and max element in an array. My code for finding the maximum works fine .. but my min prints "Minimum element in the array: 0". I probably have one little mistake that is throwing me off lol.

```
 public void deleteMin() {

  // set value for comparision starting from the beginning of the array
  int arrayMin = arr[0];

  for (int j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
     if (arr[j] < arrayMin) {
        arrayMin = arr[j];
     }
    // insert delete functionality    
  } 
  System.out.println("Minimum element in the array: " + arrayMin);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `max`?  Is it equal to `arr.length`?

Comment: Doesn't look wrong to me... Have you tried debugging your code (step-by-step execution can help you see what's going on)

Comment: yes, max is equal to arr.length. I could using arr.length instead and see if that makes a difference

Comment: You should verify that there's an element 0, also if there is one, the for-loop can start at index 1

Comment: Instead of asking this, you should insert a print statement in the loop there and display the output. That would help you far greater than over here.

Comment: Also, this is covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-using-java

Comment: So I edited my code to use nElems which in essence is the number of elements I have in it. This is because whenever I call my insert method to insert an element I increment that variable .. Verified that the change resulted in a positive result

Comment: You shouldn't have your insert / delete code in the same loop as the one being iterated over.

Comment: You sample does not compile, but if it did. You need to initialize the min element with something big so all numbers in array are for sure smaller. if you initiialize it with 0, none of them would be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is correct as it stands now. The only reason for `arrayMin` to contain 0 after the code has finished is if

- `nElems` was not set to `arr.length`, or
- 0 was indeed the smallest element in the array.

The code could be simplified.

**Java 8**:

```
int arrayMin = IntStream.of(arr).min().getAsInt();
```

**Java 7**:

```
int arrayMin = arr[0];
for (int i : arr)
    arrayMin = Math.min(arrayMin, i);
```

(Note that both solutions assume a non-empty array since min would otherwise be undefined.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
List<Integer> yourList = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);
for (int i= 0; i< arr.length; i++)
    yourList.add(arr[i]); 

Collections.min(yourList);
Collections.max(yourList);
```

See [max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) and [min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)) documentation.

Or if you have Java 8 as @ioobe already mentionned :

```
IntStream.of(arr).min().getAsInt();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use array lists .. has to be a regular array set

Answer (score 0):

If you're just iterating over the array, then utilize the fact that you can have two pointers going instead of just the one.

Hence, this can get the job done with half the number of iterations :

```
public static int minElementInArray(int[] a) {      
    int minArrayElement = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
        if (a[i] < minArrayElement) {
            minArrayElement = a[i];
        } 

        if (a[a.length - i - 1] < minArrayElement) {
            minArrayElement = a[a.length - i - 1];
        }
    }       
    return minArrayElement;
}
```