# Best way to find maximum integer inside a string array?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
String[] array = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "25"};
```

I want to find the maximum number inside that string and return it as an `integer`.

What is the best way, especially with regards to performance as I have to parse a few million rows with it?

Two solutions I can think of:

```
Arrays.stream(array).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().orElse(0);
Integer.valueOf(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array))); //.max returns 0 when empty array
```

Comment: The first one allows to parallelize easily the stream if needed. But your second implementation is wrong, so I supposed you didn't tested it. So before thinking of the "best" way, you should think of the "correct" way.

Comment: It seems that the second way is just wrong: it compares strings and just then parses the result to `int`. This means for example that 2 > 10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the max/min value in an array of primitives using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-of-primitives-using-java)

Comment: As you (or a library you chose) have to parse the string to an int before getting the max from a collection/stream etc. performance should be measured on the OS/JVM you are using. Another question is, if you can read the rows in another way than a String array - depending on the format.

Comment: You are asking for the best way. I think this is subject to opinion unless you get actual data and as @swinkler said it may depend on external factors. Just benchmark it yourself. But the Sasha comment is a good idea. I would try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposed that integers presented as `String`s are all non-negative and don't have trailing zeros, you don't need to parse them during the search. Use a custom comparator, which first compares strings by length, then by value:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
//...

String[] s = {"1", "2", "3", "25"};
Optional<String> max = Stream.of(s).max(comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(naturalOrder()));
int maxInt = Integer.parseInt(max.get());
```

Comment: You can make it slightly more elegant: `.max(comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(naturalOrder()))`

Comment: Where can I find `comparingInt` and `naturalOrder` functions?

Comment: @membersound add `import static java.util.Comparator.*;` in imports block or use `Comparator.comparingInt()` and `Comparator.naturalOrder()`