# How to find max and min value

Tags: java

So how do I find max and min value of group of numbers. Ex: The numbers are

```
int num[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,2,2,2,2,};
```

The next things is how to find out how many times 2 appears in the array.
This is what I think.

```
char a = "2"
int count = 0;
if (num.length = a) {
    count++;
    System.out.print (count);
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile.

Comment: Arrays.sort(num) then get first and last occurence.

Comment: Don't tell us what you think, tell us what you know. There are syntax errors and improper comparisons here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard clever ;)

Comment: Do you understand what that code does and why?

Comment: [`Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) is a way to count occurences

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1486010/4228138) you find a answer.

Comment: Use TreeMap of Integer,Integer ( number as key and occurence as value)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I find max and min value of group of numbers.

```
int num[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,2,2,2,2,};
getMaxValue(num);
getMinValue(num);

// getting the maximum value
public static int getMaxValue(int[] array){  
      int maxValue = array[0];  
      for(int i=1;i < array.length;i++){  
      if(array[i] > maxValue){  
      maxValue = array[i];  

         }  
     }  
             return maxValue;  
}  

// getting the miniumum value
public static int getMinValue(int[] array){  
     int minValue = array[0];  
     for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){  
     if(array[i] < minValue){  
     minValue = array[i];  
        }  
     }  
    return minValue;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For occurences use:

```
int arr = new int[10]; 
// fill arr with values;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] == 2){ counter++;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TreeMap` with key as the Number and value is the number of occurences .Then use `firstEntry()` and `lastEntry()` for getting least and maximum value.TreeMap will sort the Integers in ascending order.

```
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> tuples = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
For occurence of 2 ,simply use Integer tuples.get(2);
```