# Java min finder not working

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, min

Here are fragments of the code I have so far. My problem is that the min values come up as Integer.MAX_VALUE, instead of the value I want. iSpeedMph and pressure are both one-dimensional integer arrays.

```
    //calculating mins
    Integer min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minSpeed = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minPressure = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(i = 0; i < iSpeedMph.length; i++)
    {
        if (min > iSpeedMph[i])
        {
            min = iSpeedMph[i];
            minSpeed = iSpeedMph[i];
        }
    }

    min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(i = 0; i < pressure.length; i++)
    {
        if (min > pressure[i])
        {
            min = pressure[i];
            minPressure = pressure[i];
        }
    }
...
    System.out.printf("%7s%2s%-9s%4s%8s%5s%13.3s%5s%16.2s\n", "Minimum",  " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", minPressure, " ", minSpeed);
```

When I print out the last line, the terminal shows 214 for pressure and 21 for speed, which, without the formatting, means that they are both Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Simple mistakes like this one are the most annoying, hand in there!

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the current item is greater than the current min, which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but you want to check if the current item is less than the current min instead, e.g.

```
if (iSpeedMph[i] < min)
```

and likewise for the other min determinations.

Answer (score 2):

The test

```
if (iSpeedMph[i] > min)
```

always returns `false`. You have to **reverse the comparison**.

```
if (iSpeedMph[i] < min)
```

or as alternative

```
if (min > iSpeedMph[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

The below condition will never become true for any integer, since `min` is `Integer.MAXVALUE`.

```
if (iSpeedMph[i] > min)
```

just initialize it 0, to check if you are searching min of all in array or, assign min with first array value and loop the array from 2nd element.

Answer (score 0):

`if (iSpeedMph[i] > min)` how could this give you the new min value?

Also, please use `min` methods already written for you, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658144/499922

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you have the comparison in the if statements wrong. But finding min and max in arrays is very simple with Java 8 streams :

```
int minSpeed = Arrays.stream(iSpeedMph).min().get();
int minPressure = Arrays.stream(pressure).min().get();
```