# Min value array of int with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to get the min value of an array of int with streams, I'm trying to do something like:

```
public static int smallestInt(int[] args) {
    return Arrays.stream((Arrays.stream(args)
                .boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new ))
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).min().getAsInt;
}
```

My question is what's the best way to do it?

PS: There's a similar question but without sterams here
[Finding the max/min value in an array of primitives using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-of-primitives-using-java)

Comment: And it doesn't work? If so, what fails? And generally ... where is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're over-complicating it.

```
IntStream.of(args).min().getAsInt()
```

Note: this will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the array is empty, which is probably a desirable result.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using too much streams.

It will just do so:

```
int theMin = Arrays.stream(args).min().getAsInt();
```

As the method parameter *args* is already an array of integers according to the method signature:

```
public static int smallestInt(int[] args) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just use, it's easier to understand and *proper* :

```
public static int smallestInt(int[] args) {
     return Arrays.stream(args).min().getAsInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most others have provided good solutions, but they didn't cover the case of no smallest value at all, this should cover that case too:

```
public static int smallest(int[] ints){
    return Arrays.stream(ints).min().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: I don't like that solution. How do I, as a caller of this function, know whether the smallest int in my array *was* `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, or whether the array was empty? The correct thing to do if the array is empty is to throw an exception, which `getAsInt` already does.

Comment: @Michael you have a point. Maybe it's better to return the IntOptional directly, then the caller can decide himself what happens when no value is present

Comment: Yeah, that would be better.