# How to use Scanner get store input in one integer

Tags: java

How can I make it so the there will be the same number of questions as the user inputs the number of jobs. For example, lets say you had worked in 5 jobs, I want the program to ask the user to ask, 
Your salary for job 1
Job 2
Job 3
Job 4 
Job 5, and so on. My code right now is.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class Personal_Info {
public static void main(String[] args) {


     Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Salary1;
    int Salary2;
    int Salary3;
    int TotalJobs;
    int Average;
    String Name;
    int Largest;
    int Smallest;
    int Sum;


     System.out.print("What is your first name?: ");
    Name = Scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("How many jobs have you had?: ");
    TotalJobs = Scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter income from job #1: ");
    Salary1 = Scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter income from job #3: ");
    Salary2 = Scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter income from job #3: ");
    Salary3 = Scanner.nextInt();
    Sum = Salary1 + Salary2 + Salary3;
    Average = Sum / TotalJobs;

     Largest = Salary1;
    Smallest = Salary1;

    if(Salary2 > Largest)
        Largest = Salary2;

    if(Salary3 > Largest)
        Largest = Salary3;

    if(Salary2 < Smallest)
        Smallest = Salary2;

    if (Salary3 < Smallest)
        Smallest = Salary3;

    System.out.println("Hello " + Name + "You've had " + TotalJobs + " jobs. " + "The highest paying job paid is " + Largest + ". The lowest paying job paid is "+ Smallest + ". The average is " + Average + ".");
```

but it wouldn't work cause it'll only ask the user three times, job 1, 2, and 3.

If I try,

```
for (int x = 0; x<TotalJobs; x++){ 
 System.out.print("How many jobs have you had?: "); 
 number = Scanner.nextInt();
```

I don't know how to get the highest/smallest/average from that stored value which would be 'number'.

Comment: learn to use arrays

Comment: Your variable name is against convention. Just use 'sc' or 'scanner'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help You

```
    class SalaryCalculate{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    int totalJobs,jobcounter,maxSalary,minSalary,averageSalary=0;;
    int[] jobsincome;
    String name;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    name=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many jobs you had");
    totalJobs= sc.nextInt();
    jobsincome= new int[totalJobs];
    for(int i=0;i<totalJobs;i++){
        jobcounter=i+1;
        System.out.println("Enter the income for your job "+jobcounter);
        jobsincome[i]=sc.nextInt();
        averageSalary=averageSalary+jobsincome[i];
    }
    jobsincome=average(jobsincome);
    maxSalary=jobsincome[totalJobs-1];
    minSalary=jobsincome[0];
    averageSalary=averageSalary/totalJobs;
    System.out.println("Hi "+name+" your min salary is "+minSalary+" max salary is "+maxSalary+" average salary is "+averageSalary);
    }
    public static int[] average(int jobsincome[]){
        int length=jobsincome.length;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++){
                if(jobsincome[i]>jobsincome[j]){
                    int temp=jobsincome[j];
                    jobsincome[j]=jobsincome[i];
                    jobsincome[i]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return jobsincome;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, could you please explain the second part of the code. `public static int[] average(int jobsincome[]){
        int length=jobsincome.length;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++){
                if(jobsincome[i]>jobsincome[j]){
                    int temp=jobsincome[j];
                    jobsincome[j]=jobsincome[i];
                    jobsincome[i]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return jobsincome;`
 I don't quite understand this part.

Comment: Hi sayajin glad to know that it's helpfull for you second part just perform sorting to get min and Max salary first it will compare the values of full array then perform sort in ascending order so the value at first index will be min and the value at last index will be max.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array.

Also only capitalize classes, not variables

```
System.out.print("How many jobs have you had?: ");
int totalJobs = scanner.nextInt();
int[] salaries = new int[totalJobs];

// Loop here 
// System.out.print("Enter income from job #"+x);
// salaries[x] = scanner.nextInt();
```

With this list, you can get the length directly and use separate loops for the sum, min, max. [Or streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692454/2308683)

With the sum and length, find an average

Answer (score 2):

use an integer arraylist to keep salaries and loop through inputs

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> sallaries = new ArrayList<>();
    int TotalJobs;
    double average;
    String name;
    int largest;
    int smallest;

    System.out.print("What is your first name?: ");
    name = input.nextLine();


    System.out.print("How many jobs have you had?: ");
    TotalJobs = input.nextInt();

    for (int i= 0; i<TotalJobs ; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter income from job #"+(i+1)+" : ");
        sallaries.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    average = sallaries.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average().orElse(-1);

    largest = Collections.max(sallaries);
    smallest = Collections.min(sallaries);


    System.out.println("Hello " + name + "You've had " + TotalJobs + " jobs. " + "The highest paying job paid is " + largest + ". The lowest paying job paid is "+ smallest + ". The average is " + average + ".");
}
```

Comment: Is that `mapToInt` necessary?

Comment: @cricket_007: yes. average() can only be applied to a object which has type of an IntStream (see Java IntStream)