# An Issue with methods, am I missing something? -> The method foo in this type/class is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java

I would like to print a number in the `main()` method which is the result returned from method `foo()`. What should I do? Am I missing something?
I'm just exercising programming by making different pseudo-codes into an actual thing or well, functional...

This is the whole program, that I'm working on:

```java
public class programB {

     /* PSEUDO CODE:
     * 
     * foo(A)
       n ← A.length
       x ← A[1]
       for i ← 2 to n do
       if A[i] > x then
       x = A[i]
       return x
                 */

    int array [] = {3,4,1,2,5};

    static int foo(int[] array){
        int n = 5;
        int x = array[1];

        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
            if(array[i] > x){
                x = array[i];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        foo();
    }
}
```

This is the error, that I'm getting:

> Error: The method foo(int[]) in the type programB is not applicable for the arguments ()

Something about the method's arguments not being applicable...
Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: This error can be reworded as: The method foo(int[]) must b called by passing an int array as argument, but you're not passing anything.

Comment: `foo(array);` and arrays start at `0` (not `1`). Also, `array` must be `static` to access from `main`. And `array[5]` will be an out of bounds, use `array.length` (and `<` not `<=`, because arrays start at `0`).

Comment: If you're trying to just find the max element, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-of-primitives-using-java

Comment: Spoiler: After you resolve the _not applicable for the arguments_ error, you will get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. (Don't say I didn't warn you :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I've just completed the whole program, it runs just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

make your array static

```
static int array [] = {3,4,1,2,5};
```

call it in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] arguments){
        foo(array);
    }
```

Comment: It worked! I just had to put the 'static' prefix in front of the array initialization sentence. I also had to change the <= operator in the 'for' loop to the < operator only, as Elliott Frisch stated above.Thank you!