# I want to find min/max value within for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

How to find the min / max value using for-loop. I searched this but did not find it.I want to some help.

Comment: In what kind of structure is your min/max value stored? A `List`? A `Set`? A `Map`?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-find-Min-Max-numbers-in-a-java-array

Comment: How does your code look so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the max/min value in an array of primitives using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-of-primitives-using-java)

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think so is easy

```
    int [] tabMaxMin = {1, 4, 8, -4, 11, 0};
    int max = tabMaxMin[0];
    int min = tabMaxMin[0];
    for (int i=1; i < tabMaxMin.length; i++) {
        if(min >= tabMaxMin[i])
            min = tabMaxMin[i];
        if(max <= tabMaxMin[i])
            max = tabMaxMin[i];
    }
    System.out.println("MAX=" + max);
    System.out.println("MIN=" + min);

}
```