# Collections.max gives me an error in java, can anyone please Assist?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java.util.scanner

here is the code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class task2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n;
    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements you want to store: ");
    // reading the number of elements from the that we want to enter
    n = numbers.nextInt();
    // creates an array in the memory of length 10
    int[] array = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      // reading array elements from the user
      array[i] = numbers.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Array elements are: ");
    // accessing array elements using the for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("The max value is: " + Collections.max(numbers));
  }
}
```

I am getting an error saying "The method max(Collection<? extends T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Scanner)"

If anyone could please help that would be great, please keep in mind that I am an absolute beginner in java, so please forgive me for for any silly mistakes that I've made.

Comment: `numbers` is a `Scanner`. What is the `max` of a `Scanner`?

Comment: I am trying to get the max value from the input that ive entered in the arrays

Comment: @AMalak then you need to do something with the arrays, not the scanner you used to read values from the input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-of-primitives-using-java

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.max(numbers)
```

doesn't work because `numbers` is a `Scanner`. "The max of a `Scanner`" doesn't make sense: it doesn't have maximum or minimum values, it's a thing that just gives you one value at a time.

You need to do something with the arrays that you read values into.

You can't do `Collections.max(array)`, because `array` is an array, not a collection. You can make some arrays (those with reference-typed elements like `String[]`, `Object[]` etc) into collections using `Arrays.asList(...)`; but you can't do that with `array` because it's an `int[]`. Or rather, you *can* do that with `array`, but you get a `List<int[]>`, which you can't pass to `Collections.max` either, because `int[]` doesn't have a natural ordering.

What you can do instead is either:

- Change the type of `array` from `int[]` to `Integer[]`: then `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(...))` will work;
- Replace `int[] array` with `List<Integer> list`, and `add` instead of setting elements;
- Use `IntStream.of(array).max().orElseThrow()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements you want to store: ");
    // reading the number of elements from the that we want to enter
    final Integer n = numbers.nextInt();
    // creates an array in the memory of length 10
    final List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(10);
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // reading array elements from the user
        array.set(i, numbers.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("Array elements are: ");
    // accessing array elements using the for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(array.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("The max value is: " + Collections.max(array));
}
```